# "Harmless" script which downloads malicious script

Tags: virus, antivirus, social-engineering

What if I code a program without malicious code which would pass in every antivirus scan and after the virus scan and user giving special rights to it, it downloads and executes the real virus? Since the first step was successful to get admin rights, the next steps are easy, sure?

Comment: Viruses already do this. AV software already checks for things like this.

Comment: <joke>In the javascript world, this is called Google Tag Manager™</joke>

Answer (score 1):

You can always come up with ways to bypass real-world virus scanners. Scanners look for data present in known viruses. They can't look for exact matches in executable files. That would mean virus programmers could evade detection by changing one byte of the file without having an impact on the behavior of their executables.

Virus scanners instead look for patterns. Peculiarities found in samples of a virus are selected to attempt to sort of fuzzy-match executables with samples of known malware. There is an inevitable false-negative/false-positive trade off in this selection process.

There is no way any scanner can catch 100% of all malware. There are more forms that malware can take than there are forms virus scanner can look for. There is also no way to programmatically determine with certainty whether a program is harmless or not for all possible executable files. An anti-virus cannot mindread, so it doesn't know the difference between a program that only does what the user wants it to do and a file that does something that the user doesn't want it to do.

(That's ignoring the fact that it's not possible to tell what some programs will do without executing them. See "halting problem".)

We have never been able to rely on virus scanners. There have always been false positives and false negatives. Traditional virus scanners can also only detect viruses that the world has already seen. If it's a new type of virus, then a scanner won't be able to detect it until after people have been victimized.

More advanced anti-malware systems might profile the behavior of programs and terminate a process if it appears suspicious. This might capture some additional previously-unseen malware, but the problems of false positives/negatives and inability to distinguish malicious behavior from benign behavior still puts serious limitations on anti-virus systems.

A virus scanner then may try to look for the kind of behavior you describe. It's possible (with a performance penalty) to look for the presence of an interpreter or for downloaded scripts in network packets. However, interpreters of different varieties are common in benign programs. The downloaded script could also be encrypted, obfuscated, or hidden in legitimate traffic using steganography. So even if a virus scanner tries to detect this kind of behavior, it would be virtually impossible to detect all malware.

Any kind of anti-malware is probably a lot, lot, lot less effective than the average person believes them to be.

---

Now for the really scary part. It's not required for a malicious person to trick you into running a seemingly "harmless" executable before delivering malware in a second download. Often they can use a benign (but harmful, because they have exploitable bugs) program which users typically already have installed on their computer.

Software that downloads and runs programs with admin privileges is ubiquitous. It's called "auto-update".

Real world auto-update mechanisms are frequently implemented in such a way that attackers are free to run whatever code they want if they can spoof the update server.

A malicious update file can be substituted for a benign one. An easy way to do that would be to wait for the domain of the update server of unmaintained software to expire and take control of that domain.

That's not strictly necessary, though. A man-in-the-middle attack is also an easy task if update packages are not authenticated or if there is any mistake in the authentication checking code. (Both of which are too common.)

Crucially, to prevent this kind of attack, a **digital signature system should be employed with public key pinning** in any auto-update mechanism.

*(And that's, obviously, only good as long as the private key is never revealed to untrusted parties, trusted parties don't turn untrustworthy [I read that this happens often with Chrome browser addons, for example], the code is implemented flawlessly, and the original download of an application is legitimate.)*

Comment: "virus programmers could evade detection by changing one byte of the file" Source? Are virus scanners really THAT unintelligent?

Comment: @ig-dev Virus scanners based on signatures will issue a false negative if the signature doesn't match. The question is how well is the signature written, which is sometimes quite poorly. There are heuristic-based scanners which assess similarity (either at the file/bit level or the behavioral level) that can detect slightly modified malware or polymorphic viruses. There are also behavior-based intrusion detection suites that do not care about the source executable at all.

Comment: @ig-dev Sorry. I meant that a hypothetical virus scanner with that behavior would be almost useless. That's why they use other methods instead.